# Export Html table into Excel Format

Tags: javascript, html, spring-boot

can someone help me to figure out. How to export an html table to excel with border in its format. Our project are currently using Spring, and the frontend part was currently using bootstrap. I tried different solutions but I'm stack on it.

HTML

```
<div class="generateExcelFile">
                <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('transactionsTable', 'SettlementTransactions')" class="btn btn-primary">
                    <i class="fa fa-download"></i> Export Transaction History
                </button>
            </div>
```

JavaScript

```
    function exportTableToExcel(transactionsTable, filename = ''){
    var downloadLink;
    var dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
    var tableSelect = document.getElementById(transactionsTable);
    var tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
    
    // Specify file name
    filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
    
    // Create download link element
    downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    
    document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    
    if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
        var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
            type: dataType
        });
        navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
    }else{
        // Create a link to the file
        downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
    
        // Setting the file name
        downloadLink.download = filename;
        
        //triggering the function
        downloadLink.click();
    }
}
```

The code was based on this site: https://www.codexworld.com/export-html-table-data-to-excel-using-javascript/

Thanks.

Comment: If you are comfortable to using Jquery , Then please try with this link
https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-convert-html-table-into-excel-spreadsheet-using-jquery/

For Javascript
https://codepedia.info/javascript-export-html-table-data-to-excel

Comment: I'm not familiar enough in Jquery sir. but thank you for recommending it. My only concern is only apply it with a border or just make it simple format of excel like showing its grid while downloading.

Answer (score 1):

exportTableToExcel('transactionsTable', 'SettlementTransactions') 
make sure that *id='transactionsTable'* is in the table tag.

```js
function exportTableToExcel(transactionsTable, filename = ''){
  let downloadLink;
  const dataType = 'application/vnd.ms-excel';
  const tableSelect = document.getElementById(transactionsTable);
  const tableHTML = tableSelect.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');
  
  // Specify file name
  filename = filename?filename+'.xls':'excel_data.xls';
  
  // Create download link element
  downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
  
  document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
  
  if(navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob){
      var blob = new Blob(['\ufeff', tableHTML], {
          type: dataType
      });
      navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob( blob, filename);
  }else{
      // Create a link to the file
      downloadLink.href = 'data:' + dataType + ', ' + tableHTML;
  
      // Setting the file name
      downloadLink.download = filename;
      
      //triggering the function
      downloadLink.click();
  }
}
```

```css
.styled-table {
  border-collapse: collapse;
  margin: 25px 0;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  min-width: 400px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
}

.styled-table thead tr {
  background-color: #009879;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-align: left;
}

.styled-table th,
.styled-table td {
    padding: 12px 15px;
}

.styled-table tbody tr {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #dddddd;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:nth-of-type(even) {
  background-color: #f3f3f3;
}

.styled-table tbody tr:last-of-type {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #009879;
}

.styled-table tbody tr.active-row {
  font-weight: bold;
  color: #009879;
}
```

```html
<table id="transactionsTable" class="styled-table">
      <tr>
        <th>Order ID</th>
        <th>Order Date</th>
        <th>Customer Name</th>
        <th>Name Product</th>
        <th>Cost</th>
        <th>Amount</th>
        <th>Total</th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>02/11/2022</td>
        <td>John Doe</td>
        <td>Samsul Galaxy S21</td>
        <td>$800</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>2</td>
        <td>06/11/2022</td>
        <td>Michael</td>
        <td>Lenopo G40</td>
        <td>$200</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$200</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>3</td>
        <td>14/11/2022</td>
        <td>Ali</td>
        <td>Uphone 20 Pro</td>
        <td>$1700</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$1700</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>4</td>
        <td>18/11/2022</td>
        <td>Hendri</td>
        <td>Banana MasBook</td>
        <td>$2000</td>
        <td>1</td>
        <td>$2000</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <br />
    <button onclick="exportTableToExcel('transactionsTable', 'SettlementTransactions')">
      Export Table Data To Excel File
    </button>
```

My codepen : https://codepen.io/maulanadata/pen/KKeoOPW

Comment: Hello thank you for commenting but still work the same. after I click the export button the excel file still the same, it shows non grid or any border.